# URL Rewrite: Rewrite URL with unexisting Path

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewriting

I currently have an URL:

```
http://someDomain.com/SomeVirtualDirectory/SomeDb/SomeFileID
```

Which i would gladly rewrite to

```
http://someDomain.com/SomeVirtualDirectory/Get.aspx?page={REQUEST_URI}"
```

I currently used the following `Inbound Rule`:

```
        <rule name="CatchAll" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://someDomain.com/SomeVirtualDirectory/Get.aspx?page={REQUEST_URI}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>>
```

I've noticed that no Rewrite seems to be occuring (using Fiddler etc...). Any idea whether it is possible to use `URL Rewrite` **If the path (`SomeDb/SomeFileID` in this case) does not exist on the server?**

Thank you for your time and have a pleasant weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with some luck:

```
        <rule name="CatchAll" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Get.aspx?page={R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
```

I hope it can be of any help for someone. The main reason why the `Rewrite` didn't work was because I had set `StopProcessing` to true.